# Can I create a chatter group dynamically through apex code

Tags: apex, chatter

Is there any way to create chatter group through apex code

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

[sample code link](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Create-chatter-group-using-apex/td-p/202741)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Chatter in Apex (classes in the ConnectApi namespace) or sObjects. There are examples for both in this post:

[How to dynamically creating chatter groups in Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18666/how-to-dynamically-creating-chatter-groups-in-apex?rq=1)